# kafka abort messages ignore configuration of retries?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I work with the latest kafka version (0.10.1.1)
Here is part of my kafka config:

```
    props.put("acks", "all");
    props.put("retries", Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

i just don't want to abort any message ,but when i close the network for a while and then reconnect,kafka do not retries,i follow into the code and find:

RecordBatch.maybeExpire
....

```
   else if (this.inRetry() && requestTimeoutMs < (now - (this.lastAttemptMs + retryBackoffMs))) {
        expire = true;
        errorMessage = (now - (this.lastAttemptMs + retryBackoffMs)) + " ms has passed since last attempt plus backoff time";
    }
```

here will abort the message.

am i misunderstanding ,what should i do ? 
ajust requestTimeoutMs or retryBackoffMs ?

Comment: I don't think expire and abort are the same thing in this case, I think it just backs off a bit before trying to send again. You can find a full list of the producer configurations here: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs so you can change the back off time and the request time off to something small for testing purposes, I suggest setting your retries to a smaller number than max int as well so you can see the entire flow while debugging.

Comment: thanks, i do misunderstand the  retry.backoff.ms  the default value is 100ms  ...

Comment: How did you identify that retrying did not happen?

Comment: this.inRetry() is true,retry happened,but aborted  after a few times